# How to "reset" an entire script in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a method to return the an entire JS script to its original form? I've got a script for a quiz I'm writing, and by the end of it the arrays are shuffled and shifted and some other variables are changed as well. Is there some way to just reset the entire thing to how it was at the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

You can either manually do it by resetting all variables or use classes where you store data (then throw instances away & create new instances) or just reload the page.